# Shoddy bamboo board flooring installation - will stopgap repair cause problems later?

Tags: hardwood-floor, installation

I posted about 4 months ago on the subreddit about my experience with a con-flooring installer who installed about 300 sqft of bamboo flooring in my living/dining room. I was naive and didn't properly assess his work until it was too late. Long story short, he used very few nails and so many boards were lose. I handled some of the most egregious cases early on after the job was finished by face nailing (2.5 inch) at an angle into the boards and also by removing the last 5 rows of flooring and completely redoing them. This alleviated the majority of the issues at the time.

Well, several months later, I'm noticing quite a bit of creaking and even some up and down motion on many of the boards on my floor. While I'm mostly angry at myself for not being more assertive and discriminant, I am looking for solutions.

I see two paths forward.

1. just cut my losses and pay someone to uninstall and reinstall all of the flooring.
2. carefully face nailing more boards at an angle and filling holes with wood filler.

My question is:

Can I just do the face nailing for now and, once that inevitably fails, pay to have it all redone properly? Or will the face nailing cause more harm than good.

Comment: Perhaps a few photos would help

Comment: I can definitely provide some. Though, you wouldn't be able to see the movement. A video would probably work better.

Comment: Hi Christopher, its not just about the movement, but to see what the job and boards look like  how you have face nailed a few so far. Otherwise the answers are just guesses.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I don't think that face-nailing could make it any worse. When/if it comes time to redo it, you'll likely need to buy new floorboards anyway.

Bear in mind that it's not guaranteed to fix the creaking. Maybe the creaking is coming from the subfloor.